# STREAMLIT wallpaper - wont show, but no errors

Tags: python, streamlit

Tried using the code below to add a wallpaper to a streamlit website I'm making but nothing shows, surprisingly no errors but no image either.

The image is in the same folder as the .py file

code:

```
@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def get_base64_of_bin_file(bin_file):
    with open(bin_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    return base64.b64encode(data).decode()

def set_png_as_page_bg(png_file):
    bin_str = get_base64_of_bin_file(png_file)
    page_bg_img = '''
    <style>
    body {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,%s");
    background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
    ''' % bin_str
    
    st.markdown(page_bg_img, unsafe_allow_html=True)
    return

set_png_as_page_bg('wallpaper.png')
```

need help on this, been up for a while trying to find why

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the HTML-element `<body>` does support CSS in Streamlit's frontend.

Instead use the CSS-class `.stApp` to assign your style and background. For example using f-string:

```py
    f"""
    <style>
    .stApp {
      background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,{get_base64_of_bin_file(png_file)}");
      background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
    """
```

See the example from [How to Add a Background Image to Your Streamlit App | by My Data Talk | Level Up Coding](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-your-streamlit-app-96001e0377b2)